# How to apply editor filter to posts with a specific custom post type

Tags: editor

How can we apply filters only to posts with a specific custom post type? I would like some of my custom posts to start out in HTML mode for their editors.  This is what I am working with so far...

```
       add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', create_function('', 'return "html";') );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the current post type using [`get_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/) inside the callback function hooked to `wp_default_editor`:

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', 'wpse242896_wp_default_editor' );
function wpse242896_wp_default_editor( $editor ) {
    $post_type = get_post_type();

    if ( 'custom_post_type' === $post_type ) {
        return 'html';
    } else if ( 'other_post_type' === $post_type ) {
        return 'tinymce';
    }   

    return $editor;
}
```

Also, anonymous functions are generally discouraged because they can't be unhooked very easily.

Answer (score 2):

First check if we are on custom post type screen using [get_current_screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen)

Then apply [wp_default_editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_default_editor/) hook for custom post type

```
add_action( 'current_screen', 'get_current_screen' );
function get_current_screen() {
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $current_screen->post_type == 'custom_post_type' ) {
        add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', 'cpt_set_default_editor' );
    }
}

function cpt_set_default_editor() {
    $editor = 'tinymce'; // visual mode
    // $editor = 'html'; // Text mode
    return $editor;
}
```